# I'm setting up an IRCd on My VPS. How do I open up the normal IRC ports?

Tags: port-forwarding, irc, ircd

I'm trying to get my IRCd running on my VPS. 
I have everything set up and ready, but I cannot connect. 
Did a portscan, and the prot isn't open. 
I have root access.

How do I open up ports 6667 and 6697?

Answer (score 1):

if iptables is running on your machine, you need to open it up for these two ports you mentioned.

to check if iptables is running, run command:

```
service iptables status
```

if it is running, edit the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file and enter these two lines:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 6667 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 6697 -j ACCEPT
```

then run

```
service iptables restart
```

if iptables is not running, it might be a different matter, such as your VPS provider not allowing IRC traffic to pass thru. Read the terms of service and see if there is anything telling you something like "you can not run irc servers" or alike.

Comment: The recommended method of configuring the firewall varies by distribution. In particular, in CentOS 7 and on, it's configured using `firewalld` rather than the old `iptables` service (though the latter is still available). Might note that, depending on what OP's distro is.

Comment: @TomHunt You're absolutely right. My answer was geared towards the run-of-the-mill VPS provider, who delivers the systems with a an old version, LTS, operating system, running iptables.